# sass/node-sass issues downloading v4.10.0 from github api

Tags: node.js, github, npm, sass, github-api

Am trying to use the github api to download the node-sass dependency v4.10.0

Using the github api i am able to get the latest release v4.11.0 by using latest as the release name, however the tag v4.10.0 or any other tag is not working with api calls to single release download. How to fix this.

Below works

```
https://api.github.com/repos/sass/node-sass/releases/latest
```

Below doesn't where v4.10.0 is a valid release tag

```
https://api.github.com/repos/sass/node-sass/releases/v4.10.0
```

Error

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer thought I would post here so it would be useful to others, according to the documentation we can use tags to get individual versions

The below worked for me

```
https://api.github.com/repos/sass/node-sass/releases/tags/v4.10.0
```

Use this API and download URL we should be able to fetch all the dependencies if have issues with proxy or access gyp for node sass.